# How do I reset the keyboard hotkeys on YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

When I first load up a YouTube video's watch page, the page is in an initial state where I can use the following hotkeys:

- If I press the left (←) or right (→) arrow keys, the video skips back or forward 5 seconds
- If I press the up (↑) or down (↓) arrow keys, the volume is turned up or down

This is great. This is the ideal state that I'd always like the browser to be in. However; once I interact with the video using the mouse, the browser state changes. For example, if I use the mouse and click anywhere at all on the scrubber, then we enter this new, secondary state:

- If I press the left (←) or right (→) arrow keys, the video skips back or forward 5 seconds
- If I press the up (↑) or down (↓) arrow keys, the video skips back or forward 5 seconds

That's less than-great. Furthermore, if I use the mouse to adjust the volume, then the browser enters into a third unique state:

- If I press the left (←) or right (→) arrow keys, the volume is turned up or down
- If I press the up (↑) or down (↓) arrow keys, the volume is turned up or down

So in both of these latter cases, by using the mouse the browser then starts conflating different hotkey presses rather than retaining their initial meanings. The trouble is that I like to use both the hotkeys and the mouse, but once I've used the mouse I can't seem to get the hotkeys back into their original state. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by clicking on the dark gradient below the scrubber. Or by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus another element that isn't a slider.